# PyQt: pass the value from one class to another

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

If someone please can help me, I would like to get the value from this variable **"self.item_clicked"** from the Class First to the class Second

Thanks in advance

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('DBM.db')
conn.text_factory = str

c = conn.cursor()
#for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM typem'):
#    print(row)


class Second2(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second2, self).__init__(parent)

        #self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Close")
        #self.setCentralWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.setWindowTitle('Number')
        self.setGeometry(500, 400, 100, 100)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)
        self.label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)    

    def setValue(self, item):
        select_item = c.execute('SELECT Num FROM typem WHERE Type=?', (item, ))
        print item
        self.label.setText(item)



class First(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.add_items()
        self.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.item_click)
        self.dialog = Second2(self)


    def item_click(self, item):
        self.item_clicked = item.text()
        self.dialog.setValue(self.item_clicked)
        self.dialog.show()

    def add_items(self):
        for row in c.execute('SELECT Type FROM typem'):
            item = QListWidgetItem("{0}".format(row[0]))
            self.addItem(item)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: When you want to get it ?, where did you create an object of class First?

Comment: I want to get it when I click the item on the list to go to the second class

Comment: In which part of the second class will you use it?

Comment: You will use it in `select_item = c.execute ('SELECT a FROM FROM WHERE type = (?)', Item)`?

Comment: On the query to the database, the commented line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is create a method that receives that value and if you want in that method you process that data, as I show below:

```
class Second2(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    [...]
    def setValue(self, item):
        print(item)
        select_item = c.execute('SELECT Num FROM typem WHERE Type=(?)', item)

class First(QListWidget):
    [...]
    def item_click(self, item):
        self.item_clicked = item.text()
        print self.item_clicked
        self.dialog.setValue(self.item_clicked)
        self.dialog.show()
```

Comment: Just one question, it is possible to add a QtGui.QLineEdit on the same window of the Qlist? One on top of the other

Comment: Do you mean QListWidget?

Comment: Yes, with a QListWidget on the same window
It's to write on QLineEdit and query the database to show the results

Comment: Not directly, I recommend changing the parent of First, ie instead of using QListWidget using QWidget or QDialog, and within that widget place the QLineEdit and QListWidget

Comment: Okay :) Thank you once more